# Adding color dynamically to Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a Chart.js project, best explained by this code below.

```js
const response = [ 
   { 
      "mmyy":"2019-12",
      "promocode":"promo1",
      "amount":"2776"
   },
   { 
      "mmyy":"2020-01",
      "promocode":"promo1",
      "amount":"1245"
   },
   { 
      "mmyy":"2020-01",
      "promocode":"promo2",
      "amount":"179"
   }
];

          var chartColors = window.chartColors;
          var color = Chart.helpers.color;

          var colors = [color(chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
            color(chartColors.orange).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
            color(chartColors.yellow).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
            color(chartColors.green).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
            color(chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString()]; 

          var bgColors = [];


const labels = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.mmyy))).sort();
const promocodes = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.promocode))).sort();
const datasets = promocodes.map(pc => ({ label: pc, data: [] }));
labels.forEach(l => {    

    for (let pc of promocodes) {
      let city = response.find(c => c.mmyy == l && c.promocode == pc);
        datasets.find(ds => ds.label == pc).data.push(city ? Number(city.amount) : 0);
    }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById('promorChart').getContext('2d');

var chartColors = window.chartColors;
var color = Chart.helpers.color;

var promorChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: datasets
    },

    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              stacked: false
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              stacked: false,
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    return "$" + tooltipItems.yLabel.toString();
                }
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        elements: {
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="promorChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
```

It works great, but as you can see, it needs some color, so I am trying to add some color with this code:

```
    const labels = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.mmyy))).sort();
const promocodes = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.promocode))).sort();
const datasets = promocodes.map(pc => ({ label: pc, data: [], backgroundColor: bgColors }));
labels.forEach(l => {    

    for (var i = 0; i < labels.count.length; i++) {
            let bgColors = (colors[i % colors.length]);  
    };

    for (let pc of promocodes) {
      let city = response.find(c => c.mmyy == l && c.promocode == pc);
        datasets.find(ds => ds.label == pc).data.push(city ? Number(city.amount) : 0);
    }
});
```

But that's not working. I'm getting the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'labels.count.length')` Could someone tell me how to add a color for each of the labels properly form the color array properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code snippet, I work with simple color definitions for illustrating how it can be done. Simply replace the `colors` array with your own colors and it should work as expected.

```js
const response = [{
    "mmyy": "2019-12",
    "promocode": "promo1",
    "amount": "2776"
  },
  {
    "mmyy": "2020-01",
    "promocode": "promo1",
    "amount": "1245"
  },
  {
    "mmyy": "2020-01",
    "promocode": "promo2",
    "amount": "179"
  }
];

const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']; 
const labels = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.mmyy))).sort();
const promocodes = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.promocode))).sort();
let i = 0; 
const datasets = promocodes.map(pc => ({
  label: pc,
  data: [],
  backgroundColor: colors[i++]
}));
labels.forEach(l => {
  for (let pc of promocodes) {
    let city = response.find(c => c.mmyy == l && c.promocode == pc);
    datasets.find(ds => ds.label == pc).data.push(city ? Number(city.amount) : 0);
  }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById('promorChart').getContext('2d');

var chartColors = window.chartColors;
var color = Chart.helpers.color;

var promorChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        ticks: {
          callback: (value, index, values) => '$' + value
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItems, data) => "$" + tooltipItems.yLabel.toString()
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    elements: {}
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="promorChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to use the color scheme I have set out, custom colors. Is there another way I can do this without the use of this plugin? (I want it to match my other charts?)

Comment: @johnny: I updated my answer and adapted the code snippet according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the code. You have to set up the backgroundcolor for custom bar colors.

```
//added for colors
    function colorsFunction() {
    return ['#3e95cd','#8e5ea2'];
    }

    const labels = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.mmyy))).sort();
    const promocodes = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.promocode))).sort();
    const datasets = promocodes.map(pc => ({ label: pc, data: [],backgroundColor: colorsFunction() })); //Modified here
```

Comment: For some reason the labels aren't effected by this. The labels and the bars mismatch.

Comment: what do you mean by mismatching? can you post your output

Answer (score 0):

add this property inside our datasets => backgroundColor: ['#3a95cd','#4e5ea2']

```js
const response = [{
    "mmyy": "2019-12",
    "promocode": "promo1",
    "amount": "2776"
  },
  {
    "mmyy": "2020-01",
    "promocode": "promo1",
    "amount": "1245"
  },
  {
    "mmyy": "2020-01",
    "promocode": "promo2",
    "amount": "179"
  }
];

const labels = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.mmyy))).sort();
const promocodes = Array.from(new Set(response.map(c => c.promocode))).sort();
const datasets = promocodes.map(pc => ({
  label: pc,
  data: [],
  backgroundColor: ['#3a95cd','#4e5ea2'] //  ['#3a95cd','#4e5ea2']
}));
labels.forEach(l => {
  for (let pc of promocodes) {
    let city = response.find(c => c.mmyy == l && c.promocode == pc);
    datasets.find(ds => ds.label == pc).data.push(city ? Number(city.amount) : 0);
  }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById('promorChart').getContext('2d');

var chartColors = window.chartColors;
var color = Chart.helpers.color;

var promorChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasets
  },

  options: {
    plugins: {
      colorschemes: {
        scheme: 'brewer.DarkTwo3'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return '$' + value;
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
          return "$" + tooltipItems.yLabel.toString();
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    elements: {}
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="promorChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes"></script>
```

Comment: May I know how it differs from my answer?

Comment: There is no need of colorschemes plugin I guess

Comment: The labels and the bars are mismatched. Rendering this unusable.